# Ubuntu phone accessibility

Tags: ubuntu-touch, accessibility

I am blind and currently use an iPhone.  One of the things I like about the iPhone is its accessibility.  In fact, I'm typing this question on my iPhone.  I am able to do this because of VoiceOver, the built-in screen reader.  If a blind person such as me wanted a Ubuntu phone, what accessibility would be available?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Touch is still in its infancy. There is really only 10 or so apps currently available for Ubuntu Touch at the moment providing some core features.

I havent heard of any plans to provide a screen reader to improve accessbility. I believe there will be one eventually however as I havent seen any design plans to implement one I imagine there won't be anything within the next 3 months.

At present Ubuntu Touch can't provide what you're looking for and I can't really even provide an estimate as to when one will be implemented.

If you are able, your best bet would be to contact the mailing list for the Ubuntu Phone developers: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone